# 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to Objective C and having trouble understanding why I am getting this error. I've checked other similar questions, but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

The error is "-[NSConcreteMutableData base64Decoded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e15610"

Here is a snippet of the problem code, where the call to base64Decoded is causing the crash.

```
#import "DDData.h"

- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input
{
    NSData* dataDecoded = [[input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Decoded];    
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[dataDecoded bytes]];
}
```

And in DDData.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (DDData)

- (NSData *)base64Decoded;

@end
```

and DDData.m:

```
@implementation NSData (DDData)

- (NSData *)base64Decoded
{
     // Excluding function code, as it never gets to here
}

@end
```

Just a note that the Project has ARC enabled. Any ideas as to what might be the issue here? Thanks.

EDIT: I have adjusted the above code to help debug the error:

```
 NSData* dataDecoded = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[dataDecoded base64Decoded];
```

dataDecoded gets a value from dataUsingEncoding, it is not nil when the call to base64Decoded is made. When I step over to the called to base64Decoded, it crashes.

Comment: [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] become nil as input might nil too. so function performed on nil logs error

Comment: what does the header `.h` file of the class `NSConcreteMutableData` says? does it have such selector like `-base64Decoded`? because it seems it thrown the exception to you.

Comment: @Prince I've edited my post now to clarify. The data been sent to base64Decoded is not nil.

Comment: @holex I don't have much experience with ObjC, but I believe it is a built in type. I don't have access to the header file

Comment: @Prince -- A nil input would not cause this failure.

Comment: You need to understand the basic cause of the error:  The message is saying that you made a `base64Decoded` call to an object, but that object, which is at runtime found to be an `NSConcreteMutableData` object, does not implement that method.  (NSConcreteMutableData, if not a class you defined, is presumably an internal subclass of NSMutableData.)  You are invoking `NSString dataUsingEncoding` to produce the input to the `base64Decoded` call, so you will have some subclass of NSData.  For some reason your category is not recognized, probably because the .m file is not included in your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that kind of message if you try to execute an undefined method on an object. Try it like this:

```
NSData *dataDecoded = [[input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];
```

There is no base64Decoded method as far as I know, but there is base64EncodedString. So when you send the base64Decoded message to your NSData object, it isn't recognized because it's simply not there.

Comment: in the source code above, added the method _base64Decoded_ to class **NSData** using category.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a break point in your code and step through it and you'll see exactly where it breaks.

You may also want to check that the DDData files are properly included in your project by looking at the target membership of those files, the .m should be ticked.

Comment: I've updated the original post regarding this. It is crashing when it hits the call to base64Decoded, and I can confirm that dataUsingEncoding is not returning nil either. I've also checked that the files are included in the project, thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you check the files target membership? It may sound like the same question as are the files included in your project, but it isn't. Just want to check, apologies if this sounds like trying to teach you to suck eggs.

Answer (score 2):

SimonH pointed out the solution correctly in one of the sub-comments. I was having the same problem with a custom method i defined in a NSData category. The solution better explained:

- Make sure the .m file is included in the projects Build Phases->Compile Sources.
- Right click on the .m file in the project navigator and click "Show file Inspector". Under File Inspector make sure you check the target you are building for otherwise it wont be included and the calling that method will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below debugging steps to resolve it.

1. Put breakpoints in your code and check step by step where that is breaking.
2. Also, check if you have added `DDData.m` source file in your project target properly.
3. You should also check the object presence before using it. Check below sample code.

   ```
   - (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input {
        if(input) {
            NSData *utfData =  [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if(utfDFata) {
                NSData* dataDecoded = [utfDFata base64Decoded];    
                return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[dataDecoded bytes]];
            }
   }
   ```